# Dependency property as dialog initial directory multi-threading issue

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dialog, dependency-properties

I am making a file selector `UserControl` using a dependency property to store a string which represents the initial directory of an open file dialog :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultFolderProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultFolder", typeof(string), typeof(FileSelector), new PropertyMetadata(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())));    

public string DefaultFolder
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(DefaultFolderProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DefaultFolderProperty, value); }
    }
```

This property is bound to a `Textbox` in my `UserControl`, so I can potentially write the directory address by hand :

```
<TextBox x:Name="SelectedFolder" Style="{DynamicResource BaseTextBoxStyle}" FontSize="8" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding DataContext.DefaultFolder, ElementName=F_Selector, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

This property is also set from a browser select dialog :

```
private void SelectFolderDialog()
{
    WPFFolderBrowserDialog vfb = new WPFFolderBrowserDialog();
    vfb.InitialDirectory = @"C:";
    if (vfb.ShowDialog() ?? false)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(delegate
        {
            DefaultFolder = vfb.FileName;
        }));
    }
}
```

Now when I use this property to set the `InitialDirectory` of a select file dialog like this :

```
    private void AddFileDialog()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog vfb = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        vfb.Multiselect = true;
        vfb.Title = "pouet";
        vfb.RestoreDirectory = true;
        vfb.InitialDirectory = DefaultFolder;
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = vfb.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(delegate
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < vfb.FileNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    FileDisplay.Add(vfb.FileNames[i]);                    
                }
            }));
        }
    }
```

Whatever I use in the `InitialDirectory`property, if it is not an hardcoded directory, it doesn't work and crash my application throwing an exception :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll Additional information: 
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you post your exception's stacktrace, please?

Comment: Here is what I have so far : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: So @lecloneur you should call this code `vfb.InitialDirectory = DefaultFolder;` in the UI thread (by using the `Dispatcher` as you already did in some other parts of your code)